# Alphabet recognition

Tags: ocr

I have a picture with some writings in it. It is written by computer in to me unknown alphabet.
Is there a way how to use Mathematica to tell me what alphabet was used or what language?
Here are two versions of the same text written in to me unknown alphabets.

[image]
[image]

Comment: To solve your immediate problem: it's written in Lao : https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/lao   --- no in fact, it's closer to Thai https://unicode-table.com/en/blocks/thai/

Comment: The first one: `img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9NXm.jpg"];
TextRecognize[img, Language -> "Thai"]` gives ยาวเกานิว but this is slightly incorrect. According to google translate it should be "ยาวเก้า นิ้ว" which translates to **Nine Inches Long**

Comment: Thank you very much. How did you identify it? I know Mathematica can recognize text, but you have to tell the language. I need the opposite - to let the Mathematica tell me the language.

Comment: I just knew it was Thai :) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=tvOgIqYroiA . As for the recognizing the scripts automatically, I'll look into that.

Comment: :-D and why have you used google translator then?

Comment: So I used google translator to identify single words:
long=ยาว
nine=เก้า
inch=นิ้ว
That is all from linguistics point of view. Now I am more interested in Mathematica code, that would identify it for me.

Comment: Mathematica won't do it without knowing the language in advance. I also didn't find anything in the Wolfram Neural Net Repository. You would have to train your own. However, I've been doing some research and there's not much on whole-unicode OCR script recognition. You may want to look into this https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract , a prebuilt windows installer exists too https://github.com/UB-Mannheim/tesseract/wiki. Make sure to select additional languages/scripts when you install.

Comment: It’s worth noting that Tesseract is what is being used by `TextRecognize` in flinty’s answer, so unless there is some special argument or something that cannot be given to Tesseract through the Mathematica interface, `TextRecognize` should be sufficient.

Comment: @C. E.: What you mean by Tesseract?

Comment: @azerbajdzan Have a look at flinty’s comment just before mine.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's the list of all languages supported by `TextRecognize` in v12.1.

```
languages = {"Afrikaans", "Albanian", "Azerbaijani", "Belarusian", "Bosnian", 
  "Bulgarian", "Catalan", "Cebuano", "ChineseSimplified", 
  "ChineseTraditional", "Croatian", "Czech", "Danish", "Dutch", 
  "English", "Esperanto", "Estonian", "Finnish", "French", "Galician",
   "Georgian", "German", "Greek", "Haitian", "Hungarian", "Icelandic",
   "Indonesian", "Irish", "Italian", "Japanese", "Kazakh", "Kirghiz", 
  "Korean", "Lao", "Latin", "Lithuanian", "Macedonian", "Malay", 
  "Norwegian", "Polish", "Portuguese", "Romanian", "Russian", 
  "Serbian", "Slovak", "Slovenian", "Spanish", "Swahili", "Swedish", 
  "Tajik", "Turkish", "Ukrainian", "Uzbek", "Vietnamese", "Welsh"};
```

This will take a long time to execute the first time it downloads all the languages, so I recommend you remove languages from the list that you know aren't relevant.
The code below will recognize your text and produce a list of pairs of the form *{text, strength}*, where strength tells you if it's a good match:

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/j9NXm.jpg"];
{#, TextRecognize[img, "Line", {"Text","Strength"}, Language -> #]}&/@languages;
```

I slimmed down the list of languages to demonstrate:

```
results = {#, TextRecognize[img, "Line", {"Text", "Strength"},
 Language -> #]} & /@ {"English", "French", "Japanese", "Lao", "Thai"}

(**
   English  {gyaaniia,0.}
   French   {NN,0.}
   Japanese {ココ!せっ,0.15696}
   Lao      {ປາງເຄານິວ,0.610667}
   Thai     {ยาวเกานิว,0.941698}
**)
```

You could select the best one using: `First[MaximalBy[results, #[[2, 2]] &]]` which gives you:

`{"Thai", {"ยาวเกานิว", 0.941698}}`